# Modified javascript array reverts to old array outside of async for loop

Tags: javascript, express, for-loop, async-await

I have the following code below as an Express controller.

```
const getArticle = (req, res, next) => {
    Article
        .find()
        .populate('author')
        .then(async articles => {
            for (let i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                articles[i].author.profile = await getFirebaseUserProfile(articles[i].author.firebaseId);
            console.log(articles);
            }
            console.log(articles[i].author.profile);
            res.json({ articles });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

When the articles author profile is logged from the for loop, the firebase profile is correctly logged. But when the articles array is logged the second time outside the for loop, it is the original array with no changes made to it. Can somebody please explain how to fix it and why this happens?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not make `getArticle` an async function to begin with? I think it would clean it up a lot, since you’re mixing .then with await in here.

Comment: Good question :) . I am currently just trying to get this firebase feature to work, and then I'm gonna start cleaning up the code!

Comment: Could you show us the expected output and the erroneous output?

Comment: There should be no problem with the two `console.log(articles)` you show in your code above.  Now, if you tried a `console.log(articles)` that was outside the `.then()` handler, then that would be different because you'd be looking at `articles` before it had been filled in.

Comment: Are you logging it in a debugger and then inspecting the output? `console.log` will log the reference to the object, which can be a little weird when you are trying to step through asynchronous code. Shouldn't matter here since the for loop will block each iteration on the async result, but still worth mentioning I guess.